# How can I Do a line break on a table?

Tags: php

I have a line of `<td> &nbsp; </td>` trough a `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){`

But It is need it to show just the blanks `<td>` that I have on the result of the query.
For example if I have 14 results on my query it should show me 14 blank frames or cells.

So far I have gotten show the frames in one line but I need to do a line break or jump to the next line  every  5 frames

```
<?php session_start();
    include ("conexion.php");
?>

<?php
    $correo=$_SESSION['s_username'];
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM catalogos WHERE email = '$correo'";
    $res=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $x=1;

    echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 width=610>";
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $nom=$row["nombre_catalogo"];
        echo"<td>&nbsp;</td>";

        if(5==$x){
            echo"<br>";
            $x=0;
        }
        $x++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: That wouldn't be a line break, it would be a table row tag. Which you're not opening in the first place.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and first learn how to write the correct markup for an HTML table with mocked up data. Once you have that down, figure out how to break it up into your loop in php. It will help you out in the long run by getting the base knowledge down. There are a lot of moving pieces , and it gets overwhelming quickly when you first start out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch rows, then you need to close out the current row and start a new one. But first you have to actually properly start a row:

```
echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 width=610>";
echo "<tr>"; // Start a row
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $nom=$row["nombre_catalogo"];
    echo"<td>&nbsp;</td>";

    if(5==$x){
        echo"</tr><tr>"; // End one row and start a new one
        $x=0;
    }

    $x++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: perfect that just what i'm talking about thanks so much